# react-select - Cascading Selects MultiValue not getting cleared

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am creating a cascading kind of layout where I have two Select components for Roles and Users, the functionality I want is working fantastic except a use case where upon clearing/removing a role or clearing all roles, the Users Select component is not clearing the MultiValue items however the dataset is being cleared properly.

Please guide me as to how to achieve the said functionality, may be I am missing something or probably some kind of issue.

Here's a code snippet - https://codesandbox.io/s/l98n1o6lq7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control it via `value` attribute on `Select` in `react-select`. Following is the code you can try and manipulate accordingly -

```
<Select
  closeMenuOnSelect={false}
  isMulti
  options={showUsers}
  value={showUsers}
  hideSelectedOptions={true}
  backspaceRemovesValue={true}
/>
```

Working Demo - https://codesandbox.io/s/9z02ql079p

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, doing this will result in loosing control over the selected values in users select e.g. removing value(s) by clicking x (close) or even by clicking clear all

Comment: Thank you @swapnesh for providing the most essential pointer... for all those wondering how to use the Select, please refer to https://codesandbox.io/s/l446vwz3ll